# listbox doesnt appear on device

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am developing an app for windows phone and i had recent problem with the list box. This works fine on my emulator but when i deploy on my device, it doesn't show anything but blank. The list items are created as requested but binding doesn't carry out because each item when clicked doesn't carry information with it.
The code related to it is as follows

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="NotesListBox" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>                
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <local:NotesTile Name="TileNotes" Tap="NotesTile_Tap_1" Margin="10,10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C# code behind

```
 List<Notes> source = new List<Notes>()
            {
                new Notes(){ Content="This is some text", FileName="one.txt", IsPasswordProtected=true},
                new Notes(){ Content="Another text file", FileName="two.txt", IsPasswordProtected=false}
            };


            //this.DataContext = this;
            this.NotesListBox.ItemsSource = source;
```

In same namespace i got the class as:

```
class Notes
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string DateEdited { get; set; }
    public string TimeEdited { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPasswordProtected { get; set; }
}
```

I got things working fine on emulator and even for devices made for windows phone 8. My app got rejected on marketplace for the same reason.

**EDIT**

The Binding class should always be public. Making the class Notes as public would resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey ya!!! I just found the answer as to modify the class as public and it worked well... Can anyone tell me some reason behind it????

Answer (score 0):

try with setting `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor of the xaml.cs before InitilizeComponent() and let us know if its work.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem... The app still doesn't show any tile contents. Well this works fine on windows phone 8 as what it is said to me when i submitted to dev center. So my emulator is 8, so i think thats the reason why it is working fine on my emulator. Whats the problem in 7?